# Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue with backslashes

Tags: c#

I have a Jobject called myObject and it looks like this

```
[1] = {"1": "[\r\n  {\r\n    \"LINK_ID\": \"573320505\",\r\n    \"LONG_HAUL\": \"N\",\r\n    \"NAME\": \"39 / Želnava\",\r\n    \"NAMES\": \"ENGBN39 / Želnava\",\r\n    \"TUNNEL\": \"N\",\r\n    \"BRIDGE\": \"N\",\r\n    \"LAT\": \"4881082,12,10,11,11,4\",\r\n
```

My Problem is I don't know how to access e.g LINK_ID
Does anybody know how to access it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The json seems to contain encoded json itself. You can decode the first object and then decode the second

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with slashes. Where did this JSON string come from? Why does the `1` element contain a *string* instead of JSON ? You'll have to fix whatever produced this string. A proper JSON string is `{"1":[{"LINK_ID": "573320505" , "LONG_HAUL": "N",....`

Comment: Guys i fixed it  i made a dictionary that looks like this :

Comment: [16] = {"16": [
  {
    "LINK_ID": "573320505",
    "LONG_HAUL": "N",
    "NAME": "39 / Želnava",
    "NAMES": "ENGBN39 / Želnava",
    "TUNNEL": "N",
    "BRIDGE": "N",
    "LAT": "4881082,12,10,11,11,4",
    "LON": "1396588,-18,-16,-22,-33,-11",
    "Z...

Comment: but the only question i have left is how can I access the value for example LINK_ID